# How can we Export data from Web Published Reports

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have published an application that i did with power Bi, for some charts I want to make data downloadable for users.

I couldn't find any straight forward way to do that, some sites talk about implementing a script for that.

Is there any real way for published application that works?

Comment: What do you mean by "Web Published Reports"? Are you taking about [Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web)? Or you mean a report, published to Power BI Online workspace, which is then visible by other users with rights for this workspace/report? Why there are tags `powerbi-embedded` and `power-bi-report-server` attached to your question? What is embedded and what is related to an on-premise Power BI Report Server instance?

Comment: Yes,  Publish to web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web#limitations) of `Publish to web` is the inability to export data:

> - Reports using row level security.
> - Reports using any Live Connection data source, including Analysis Services Tabular  hosted on-premises, Analysis Services Multidimensional, and Azure Analysis Services.
> - Reports shared to you directly or through an organizational content pack.
> - Reports in a group in which you are not an edit member.
> - "R" Visuals are not currently supported in Publish to web reports.
> - **Exporting Data from visuals in a report, which has been published to the web**
> - ArcGIS Maps for Power BI visuals.
> - Reports containing report-level DAX measures.
> - Single sign-on data query models.
> - Secure confidential or proprietary information.
> - The automatic authentication capability provided with the Embed option doesn't work with the Power BI JavaScript API. For the Power BI JavaScript API, use the user owns data approach to embedding. Learn more about user owns data.

Exporting data is possible, if you publish your report in Power BI Online and [share it with your colleagues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-share-dashboards). But keep in mind, that even in this case it may not be possible or allowed, due to these [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data#limitations-and-considerations), e.g. if it has been disabled, or the user doesn't have enough permissions. In addition, it has limits on maximum columns, rows and data size.

The best option is to export the data directly from the data source, which is used to build this report.

Comment: Thank you so much ! 
Still one quick question, can I do it through a R / python script ?

Comment: Do what? Connect to the data source and export data to file? If you know where the data is and has rights to read from this data source, then yes.

Comment: I mean like this, this method still not tested on web published app : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56FV6x8vYyQ

Comment: You can't do that in Power BI Online, only with local reports in Power BI Desktop on your computer.